# FB add friend dialog on mobile doesnt work

Tags: facebook, cordova

Im using facebook add friend dialog(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/) to add friend from my app. It works just fine from desktop but when i try to use it from my mobile app i get error 500 response from the server.

Desktop friends Dialog(works)

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends?app_id=appId&id=userId&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`

Mobile friends dialog ( error 500 )

`https://m.facebook.com/dialog/friends?app_id=appId&amp;id=userId&amp;redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`

As you can se the only difference is in the m prefix. Is there some other way to send a friend request from mobile ?

Comment: Are you building a native app or a mobile web-app? I believe the above URLs work only for mobile web-apps.

Comment: Im building app with phonegap... im opening the link with inAppBrowser

Comment: can you check if this URL is supported by phonegap's inAppBrowser? I have noticed only versions of Blackberry not supporting the dialog.

Comment: it started working ... I didnt change anything. Obviously there were some api problems ...

Comment: Is it still working for you @dinodsaurus? Because it seems like it's not for most (or at least some) of us. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403197/facebook-friend-dialog-not-working-on-mobile. The [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/506955376009451) even says: "Won't fix" and I can't wrap my around it. Please help if you can.

Comment: the problem fixed itself so i think it was a fb problem... Im not working anymore on that code so I canot help sry

Answer (score -1):

in the mobile side, & amp ; is your problem. Make sure it is & only - facebook doesn't clean the urls, but they used to do that.